# Confusing step in the Laravel Homestead installation process?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, homestead

I'm going through the Laravel Homestead setup, but a particular instruction seems to be completely out of context/unexplained. I'm not at all familiar with composer, having only used npm for package management in the past.

In the 'Installing Homestead' section, under **With Composer + PHP Tool** it reads:

---

> Once the box has been added to your Vagrant installation, you are ready to install the Homestead CLI tool using the Composer global command:
>
> `composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"`
>
> **Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH so the homestead executable is found when you run the homestead command in your terminal.**

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead

---

Emphasis mine. What does this mean? What `~/.composer/vendor/bin` directory? What `PATH`? Feels like it's missing a step!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the PATH variable is slightly out of the spec of the Laravel docs as its something you should do for composer, but regardless I too think Laravel should at least link through to a resource of how to go about it.

Create/edit your `~/.bash_profile`, add the following

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

finally run `source ~/.bash_profile` to update your environment

I wrote a blog on this which goes into a little more detail http://blog.iwader.co.uk/updating-path-environment-variable-osx-and-unix-systems/

Comment: Awesome, thanks Wader! Yes it seems they cover the setup and install of VirtualBox and Vagrant, but assume that composer is already in place. (Technically of course they also don't cover setting up PHP, I guess everyone's line will be somewhere a little different)

Comment: I think they should state it clearly for those who wanna start learning php. As they might pick Laravel as first choice framework to start with, this little information may help. I also don't want to have php installation if homestead already provide it. But the composer requires it though